# mutible Language Website

Tags: php, html

My website is working with 2 languages.

I used session for that purpose. When a user clicks on a language icon the language is changed and everything is fine, but when the website is opening for the first time without choosing the language the default language is not loaded and the words do not appear.

This is my language.inc.php file

```html
<?php
session_start();
$langForSelection = isset($_SESSION['lang']) ? $_SESSION['lang'] : 'en'; //default to english language
if(isset($_GET['langSelect'])){
    //allow only 2 for now ( english / turkish)
    $langForSelection = "";
    switch($_GET['langSelect']){
        case 'en':
        $langForSelection = 'en';
        break;
        case 'tr':
        $langForSelection = 'tr';
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    if(isset($langForSelection)){
  $langForSelection2=$_SESSION['lang']=$langForSelection;
       // setcookie('lang',$langForSelection,time()+24*7*60*60);//set cookie to expire in 7 days
    }
}
```

here is the icons where user choose the language

```
    <div><a href="?langSelect=en" title="English" id="English" class="active_lang"><img src="images/united-kingdom.png" class= "active" style="float: right; width: 24px;height:24px ;padding: 4px"> </a>

<a href="?langSelect=tr" title="Turkish"  id="Turkish"><img src="images/turkey.png" style="float: right; width: 24px;height:24px; padding: 4px"> </a>
```

here I  print the translate of the words 
this is an example

```
require_once('inc/languages.inc.php'); 
require_once('Languages/common.inc.php'); 
$langForSelection2=$_SESSION['lang'];


   <li><a href="Logs.php?id=access" class="details"   data-ajax="false"><?php echo $arrLang[$langForSelection2]['log_login']; ?></a></li>
```

Again my problem is reproduced when the web page is loaded and before a user clicks on language icon the words not appear but when he click on the language click everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your switch to default to English:

```
switch($_GET['langSelect']){
    case 'en':
    $langForSelection = 'en';
    break;
    case 'tr':
    $langForSelection = 'tr';
    break;
    default:
    $langForSelection = 'en';
    break;
}
```

The reason of your problem probably is that your `$_SESSION` has a `lang` value, which is different from your expectations, like `'en-us'`. If you want to know the exact cause, you can reproduce the problem with a new session and calling `var_dump($_SESSION);` If it has a `lang`, then it is the exact reason of your problem.

EDIT:

The solution shown here was not enough, since this part

```
if(isset($langForSelection)){
    $langForSelection2=$_SESSION['lang']=$langForSelection;
   // setcookie('lang',$langForSelection,time()+24*7*60*60);//set cookie to expire in 7 days
}
```

was inside the `if`. You will need to move this outside the `if`.

Comment: @M.Bwe yes, you have the code dealing with the language inside the if, that is, this part will not run if you do not have a corresponding GET parameter, which is the case at the initial load.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: I added else {  $langForSelection = "en";
   
    if(isset($langForSelection)){
  $_SESSION['lang']=$langForSelection;
      
    }} which is the case where the $_GET['langSelect'] is not determined     but  when I load the page it working with English language and when I change language it changed till I click on any link and it returned to English how can I solve that

Comment: @M.Bwe you are welcome. If this answer solved your problem or led you to the solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.